# Cannot adjust actual speaker volume on iPhoneX and iPhone 8

Tags: ios

I'm developing VoIP application for iOS. When I try to adjust speaker sound volume for my VoIP app with side hardware buttons of iPhoneX, iPhone8 and iPhone7(iOS11) the actual sound volume is not changed. The sound level(meter with bell icon) seems to be changed anyway. I only hear all sounds with same volume via my app on the devices. I can change the speaker volume of my app on iPhone 6 plus and 6s. There're some changes for the devices recently?If so,  How can I fix it?

I use AVAudioSession and AUGraph classes to control sounds for my app. The settings are AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord and AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat, for example. In addtion, I'm using VoiceProcessingIO and RemoteIO.

FYI: Skype seems to have similar issues below.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_ios-skype_callms-skype_audioms/cant-lower-speaker-volume-on-ios-skype/14f2bac1-80bb-4608-83de-db8b491d726d

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_ios-skype_callms-skype_audioms/change-skype-volume-on-ios/2aed2915-a906-4540-8dfd-2bfd9d3714ed

Please let me know if you have some information for this issue.

Best Regards,
K.M

Comment: Have u solved this problem? Cause I met the exact same problem.